# When you setup a Visual Studio Virtual Machine on Azure, what are the default credentials for the SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure

When you setup a Visual Studio Virtual Machine on Azure, what are the default credentials for the SQL Server?

I setup a Visual Studio Virtual Machine on Azure using the template provided by Windows Azure.

What are the credentials for the SQL Server instance that gets setup alongside the VM when you do this?

I can't connect using Windows Authentication, my login credentials for Windows don't work either.

I can easily install another SQL Server instance, but I see one already running and I would like to connect to it and use it:

[image: VS Azure]

[image: VS Azure]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a case of me not [RTFM](http://visualstudio2013msdngalleryimage.azurewebsites.net/)'ing.

When you login, there is a shortcut on the desktop called **ConfigureDeveloperDesktop**, inside this directory is a directory called **Scripts** and inside here there is a Powershell script called **ConfigureSQLServer**.

After you run this, you can then use Windows Authentication to connect to the SQL Server instance and configure it as you wish.